# Can't go to App Compatibilty

Tags: iphone, ios, compatibility, 32-bit

I am running iOS 10.3.3 on an iPhone 7 plus.

When I go to `Settings > General > About`, I see Applications on the list with the number of apps I have installed. There is no ">" arrow to the right of the number of apps as I have seen in screen shots of other iPhones.

Clicking on Applications does nothing. Restarting the phone does nothing.

Anyone know why I don't have the App Compatibility screen? Do I have to turn something on somewhere else to see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe because you don’t have any 32-bit apps installed?

I don’t see the arrow as well, but I’m on iOS 11 beta and have no 32-bit apps installed (can’t install it anyway now).

So you can safely upgrade to iOS 11 the moment it's available.

Comment: That's correct.  I'm still on v10.3.3.  You will only see a disclosure arrow if you have 32-bit apps installed.  If there's no 32-bit apps then you won't have anything to display on that screen so there won't be a disclosure arrow.